Kong request transformer - inject X-User-Id: {{jwt.claim.sub}}
I have a kong api and a apollo-router running behind that. Rather to have all my microservices decrypt a token i want to inject the id after kong has accepted the token. I use oauth2 and I use openID as a plugin and it works. The token has a sub and the token is valid. But when i try to add in the request transformer, heading: X-User-Id: {{jwt.claim.sub}} i just get that out on the other side. So it looks like Kong don´t add in the information i want. So my system is  plugin OpenID and then the request transformer with this as the "add header" X-User-Id: {{jwt.claim.sub}}. I do not use customer or customer group because i want this to be injected in every user so i dont need to decrypt every token. I just need the ID of the user available so the backend microservice now witch user that asks. Maybe someone here knows what i need to add to the add header, because this want work.
I have read the docs, tried different plugins - i have tested other commands, i have decrypted the token and the sub information is available. So now I am trying here.

You can't expect request-transformer plugin to magically ✨ retrieve the JWT claims and store them in a header, that's just not what it does :)

Facts
According to the documentation page, you can use templates but:

the syntax is $(), not {{}};
there's nothing documented that handles JWTs.

Possible Solutions

custom plugins
maybe using request-transformer advanced templates and functions

Solution: custom plugins

Disclaimer: I have not tested this code, since I'm not home right now :) I'm going to do so as soon as possible.

Create a custom plugin that retrieves the JWT (e.g. from the request context) and stores the claim as a header:
File handler.lua:
local jwt_decoder = require("kong.plugins.jwt.jwt_parser")
local set_header = kong.service.request.set_header

local CustomHandler = {
  VERSION  = "1.0.0",
  PRIORITY = 10,
}

-- Other stuff

function CustomHandler:access(conf)
  -- Retrieve the token from the context
  local token = kong.ctx.shared.authenticated_jwt_token
  if not token then
    kong.log.warn("Token not found in context")
    
    return kong.response.exit(500, "TEST: Token not found in context")
  end

  local jwt = jwt_decoder:new(token)
  local user_id = jwt.claims.sub
  if not user_id then
    kong.log.warn("'sub' claim not found in JWT")
    
    return kong.response.exit(500, "TEST: 'sub' claim not found in JWT")
  end

  -- set the header
  set_header("X-User-Id", user_id)
end

return CustomHandler

File schema.lua:
local typedefs = require "kong.db.schema.typedefs"

return {
  name = "jwt-sub-to-header",
  fields = {
    { config = {
        type = "record",
        fields = {
    }, }, },
  },
}

Then follow the custom plugin guide to install and use it.
Test: request-transformer functions
Example:
curl -X POST http://localhost:8001/services/{serviceName|Id}/plugins \
    --header "accept: application/json" \
    --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
    --data '
{
  "name": "request-transformer",
  "config": {
    "add": {
      "headers": [
        "X-User-Id:$((function()
          -- Load JWT decoder from jwt plugin
          local jwt_decoder = require(\"kong.plugins.jwt.jwt_parser\")

          -- Retrieve the token from the context
          local token = kong.ctx.shared.authenticated_jwt_token
          if not token then
            -- Handle missing token in context
            return
          end

          local jwt = jwt_decoder:new(token)
          local user_id = jwt.claims.sub
          if not user_id then
            -- Handle missing sub claim in token
            return
          end
          
          return user_id
        end)()
        )"
      ]
    }
  }
}
'

This code should retrieve the token from the request context, parse it, and add
the header X-User-Id:<sub> with <sub> being the claim value.
However, I tested this and it doesn't work due to the request transformer using a sandboxed environment to run the Lua code. Here's the error:
error:/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/tools/sandbox.lua:88: require 'kong.plugins.jwt.jwt_parser' not allowed within sandbox

I didn't investigate further since the first solution should work just fine.

Briliant! I agree i also thought it was a bit weird that it should just "know" it. But i heard and i also read som placed that it should work. Thank you, I will test it as sonn as i have painted the kitchen. Somebody expect me to do that :) Again, thanks!

But again - what about "upstream_headers_claims"?

Ok so yes! The OIDC, openID plugin can be used for this. So upstream_headers_claims parameter should be set to sub and the upstream_headers_names parameter should be set to X-User-ID. When this is done the user ID, from the sub, is sent with the token. So no need for a custom plugin.
